# Every number less than $n!$ can be written as a sum of at most $n$ divisors.

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that, for every $n > 1$, any number that is less than $n!$ can be written as a sum of at most $n$ distinct divisors of $n!$. [Hint: Use induction and Euclidean division with remainder].

Comment: I recommend trying this for some small numbers to get a raw feel for what's going on, say numbers up to 30ish. (And so n up to 5ish.)

Comment: Presumably, not $n$ up to 30, @anon, that might be messy. :) Presumably, try $n=5$ and $m$ some values bigger than $24$.